# HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase does not exist in namespace 'System.Web'

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, compilation, nuget-package

I installed the System.Web nuget package in the .net framework project, but for some reason it is not able to recognized the HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase class and it just showed red underlined under the HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase.

```
public System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase HttpBrowserCapabilities { get; }
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install anything through NuGet. Just reference System.Web through Assemblies like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHY25.png